# Style barbutton in xcode

Tags: xcode, button, ios6, navbar

I am trying to stylize my button in navbar. But i get it wrong, the png is right, but with the code i got this.

http://i50.tinypic.com/o73tr5.png

Can anyone help me please.

I am using this code

> ```
> UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
> ```

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you forgot to add the file extension. Here is an example of how to define a UIImage.

```
blackBackgroundButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_13.png"];
```

If that doesn't work let me know.

Comment: It also works without the file extension. I tried included .png and it`s the same.

Comment: Hmm. Alright, how about you add a UIImageView to the view, and try to load that image into it and see if it works. At least that way we know that it is the second line of code (Or some mysterious line), but not the first.